# Interesting number theory pattern with proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, pattern-recognition

I have found the following number pattern to hold true 
$$333*576=191808$$ 
$$333000333*576=191808191808$$ 
$$333000333000333*576=191808191808191808$$…
And so on. My question, then, is how might I prove that this pattern holds, rather than simply stating it does. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: $333000333 = 333(1000000+1)$, so $333000333\cdot 576 = (333\cdot 576)(1000000+1) = 191801(1000000+1) = 191808191808$. Generalize. (There is nothing special here about either $333$ or $576$; the result holds for any two three-digit numbers.)

Comment: @rogerl i.e. it's just *associativity:* $\,(ab)c = a(bc)\,$ for $\,a,b,c = 10^6\!+1,\,333,\,576\ \ \ $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write the products alternatively as
\begin{eqnarray*}
333\times576&=&191808\times1&=&191808\\
333000333\times576&=&191808\times1000001&=&191808191808\\
333000333000333\times576&=&191808\times1000001000001&=&191808191808191808
\end{eqnarray*}
This is independent of the six-digit number $191808$ or its particular factorization $333\times576$.
Is there anything more to prove here?

Comment: i.e. it's just *associativity:* $\,(ab)c = a(bc)\,$ for $\,a,b,c = 10^6\!+1,\,333,\,576\ \ \ $